# netbeans 6.8 word wrap

Tags: netbeans6.8, word-wrap

Does anyone knows of a way to wordwrap in NetBeans 6.8?

I have been looking around and I can't find a solution for that problem, yet it is really hard to believe that such a basic feature is still missing in NetBeans.

I like very much working in NetBeans, but not having wordwrap prompts me to add hard returns inside my code where they really shouldn't be, and that feels "unclean". It also causes a lot of extra work when editing the pages later, so I would really like to find a way to wrap the text to the window.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255862/word-wrap-in-net-beans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wasn't word wrapping in Netbeans [more than one year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255862/word-wrap-in-net-beans).

[Bug 89894](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89894) may indicate such a feature for the next release after Netbeans 6.9 though.

> > When you say line wrap is turned off in 6.9 beta, does that mean disabled by
> >     default, but we can turn it on? Or does it mean not available at all?
> >     I'd upgrade to the beta if word wrap was there to test out, if not I'll just wait.
>
> This feature was removed from 6.9 and **will be turned on again for 6.9.next and hopefully it will be stable for next release**.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I will have to wait for that one.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is back in Netbeans.  To to tools -> options -> editor -> formatting -> Line Wrap

See [Word Wrap in Netbeans](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2012/01/wordwrap-in-netbeans/)