# A simple Netbeans IDE question

Tags: netbeans

Is there a way to make the line of code fall on to the next line automatically when it reaches the end of the screen. For me the text just keeps on going horizontally until I manually press the return key. I want this to happen automatically when the text reaches the end of the screen. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255862/word-wrap-in-net-beans and http://blog.robbychen.com/2010/04/26/enable-line-wrap-option-in-netbeans-nightly/

Comment: @CurtainDog Thank You very much, the method in that post worked. If you post your comment as an answer I would be happy to choose it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it from:

1) Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Formatting(Tab)

2) Select Your Language in "Language Drop down"

3) Select "Wrapping" from Category and do what ever you want

Note: this is for Windows OS

Note 2 :Make sure you re-open the file to see the change.