# How to wrap words/lines in NetBeans IDE 6.9.1?

Tags: netbeans, windows-xp, netbeans-6.9

I searched for "wrap" in keyboard mappings without success. I don't see this option in menu  neither.

**EDIT:** I was thinking about result the you get let's say in Notepad2 by pressing Ctrl+W (or selecting View -> Word Wrap). So I'am asking about toggling such Word Wrap

Comment: can you please mark @Peter Nore as the correct answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you talking about "soft wrapping"? That is, there are no line breaks inserted into the text file, but each line is wrapped to fit in the editor window?

NetBeans doesn't support that. Hard to believe, I know. I think it might be coming in the 7.0 version, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, I mean that kind of wrapping. Wow. I am really shocked!

Answer (score 27):

In Tools->Options there is a whole section on line wrapping. The options you choose here will depend on how you need to do the wrapping - it is quite configurable.

1. Go to Tools->Options.
2. Click on Editor in the ribbon at the top.
3. Choose the  formatting tab.
4. Choose the language you require the wrapping for it the Language combobox.
5. In the Category, choose Wrapping.
6. Configure how you would like the wrapping to take place.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I was thinking about result the you get let's say in Notepad2 by pressing Ctrl+W (or selecting View -> Word Wrap). So I'am asking about toggling such Word Wrap.

Comment: Are there certain versions where the Wrapping category isn't available? On Netbeans 6.9.1 on Linux, Tabs and Indents is actually the only thing available from the "Category" drop down.

Answer (score 8):

Stolen from Sidarta's tip in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255862/word-wrap-in-net-beans):

> You can use word wrap in Netbeans.
>
> Add to netbeans.conf
>   (netbans_instalation_path/etc/netbeans.conf):
>
> -J-Dorg.netbeans.editor.linewrap=true and restart Netbeans.
>
> In Options->Editor->Formating there is
>   Line Wrap dropdown option
>
> Works fine for me in Netbeans 6.9

Answer (score 3):

Since Netbeans 7, word wrap is available.  See this blog for directions:

[Netbeans & Wordwarp](http://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2012/01/wordwrap-in-netbeans/)

Answer (score 3):

As Daniel says, after Netbeans 7 this is possible. Just go to your NetBeans options and select the editor tab. In languages (dropdown) selection choose "all languages". Then you will see the option Line Wrap. Change it to "After Words" or "Anywhere".

[image]

Comment: a picture is worth a thousand words

Answer (score 0):

Go to toolbar-> option ->Editor(Tab)

view this picture..

[soft wrap in netbean](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7w0tqgoXyiOcTBOUG9QQmY0eDA/view?usp=sharing)

select your line wrap 'after words' .

after apply these settings. you will see the code responsive way. you don't need to scroll horizontal to see code.view the picture for resutl.

[soft wrap in netbean](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7w0tqgoXyiOMDdIVjlRbGl3RVk/view?usp=sharing)